# SimpleXML adding child with children and attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have some XML to which I need to add a child.

Using SimpleXML, I'm not having any issue adding a simple node.

The beginning XML looks a bit like this:

```
<root>
    <item>
         <title>This is the title</title>
         <sort>2</sort>
    </item>
    <item>
         <title>This is another title</title>
         <sort>3</sort>
    </item>
</root>
```

I need to add a node that looks like this:

```
    <label id=1>
         <title type=normal>This is a label</title>
         <sort>1</sort>
    </label>
```

The result would be:

```
<root>
    <item>
         <title>This is the title</title>
         <sort>2</sort>
    </item>
    <item>
         <title>This is another title</title>
         <sort>3</sort>
    </item>
    <label id=1>
         <title type=normal>This is a label</title>
         <sort>1</sort>
    </label>
</root>
```

I'm able to add a simple child using:

```
$xml->root->addChild('label', 'This is a label');
```

I am having trouble getting the attributes and children added to this newly added node though.

I am not worried about appending versus prepending as the sorting happens in XSLT.

Comment: What you're trying to do is explained in the manual. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php (example #10)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

addChild returns the added child, so you just have to do :

```
$label = $xml->root->addChild('label');
$label->addAttribute('id', 1);
$title = $label->addChild('title', 'This is a label');
$title->addAttribute('type', 'normal');
$label->addChild('sort', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the cut/paste-ability -- on a time crunch. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
$xml->root->addChild('label', 'This is a label');
```

This opereration returns a reference to the child that was just added. So you could do this:

```
$child = $xml->root->addChild('label', 'This is a label');
```

From this, you can not add your additional children and attributes to that child.

```
$child->addAttributes('id', '1');
```

Since it returns a reference, that node and attributes that were just added are part of the $xml object as well.